# How to name the column being the day of the week

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this appointment, but I had to put the day of the week.

```
   select `a`.`aplicativo` AS `PROGRAMA`,
          sum((cast(`r`.`created_at` as date) = curdate())) AS `HOJE`,
          sum((cast(`r`.`created_at` as date) = (curdate() - 1))) AS `ONTEM`,
          sum((cast(`r`.`created_at` as date) = (curdate() - 2))) AS `2_DIAS`
   from (`registration` `r` 
         join `aplicativos` `a` on ((`r`.`app_id` = `a`.`id`))) 
   group by `r`.`app_id`
```

I have already tried with the following command gives error.

```
sum((cast(`r`.`created_at` as date) = (curdate() - 1))) AS DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%a %e')
```

I would like that in each column of sum, it appears

```
Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday
65       54       99        100
```

It can not be fixed, because every day will change.
Today is Sunday and will appear the dates of Saturday, Friday ...
But tomorrow is Monday then it should appear: Sunday, Saturday ....

**Tomorrow will be another result as below**

```
Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday
54       99        100         85
```

Comment: You cannot run functions on column aliases directly in query unless a stored proc. Consider also application code like PHP, Python, or R to dynamically create SQL statement with needed column alias.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi, @Gordon Linoff, can you help me with this too? I have already edited my question with the result that I need

Comment: @Parfait, I need to do this directly in the query because my report is straightforward in Mysql I do not use php, python etc ...

Comment: @William . . . A SQL result set has a set of columns with fixed names in a fixed order.  You can only do what you want using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Have an example with Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @William, dynamic SQL is run at application layer above database where a general purpose language (php, python, r, vb, c#, java, perl) builds a dynamic string SQL statement by conditional/logical criteria and sends it as a call to database. Your needs require a recreated query every day.

Comment: Thank you guys
I'll leave the name of the columns fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.aplicativo AS programa,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dayofweek(r.created_at)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sunday,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dayofweek(r.created_at)=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS monday,
  /* ... */
  SUM(CASE WHEN dayofweek(r.created_at)=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS saturday
FROM registration r
  JOIN aplicativos a ON a.id=r.app_id
WHERE r.created_at>=(curdate()-6)
GROUP BY a.aplicativo
```

Comment: This way it would sum to the day of the week example: Sum all of the day of the week in the case Sunday.
That's not what I need! I need it to show All downloads for Today Sunday and the name of the Column = Sunday. Tomorrow will be Monday so the column should change to Monday

Comment: Look at WHERE clause: the query doesn't sums data for all sundays, all mondays etc. It sums data only for today and the 6 previous days. So it's exactly what you need EXCEPT the order of columns is fixed.

Comment: Again, @William, SQL is a special-purpose, declarative language where structural components like tables/columns once referenced are immutable though data can change. You need to recreate this query **every** day. Reconsider general purpose languages like aforementioned Python, PHP, R each with great APIs to MySQL.

Comment: The only other way is to build your query dinamically, as Gordon Linoff told already.

Comment: Thank you guys
I'll leave the name of the columns fixed.